# How to get the status of savepoint() in jdbc3

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, savepoints

I have three savepoint for three different database. I want to find out from which transaction, exception rose. So basically these transaction are running sequentially. If exception occurs in transaction 1 ,Then I have to rollback to savepoint 1.

if exception occurs in transaction2 ,then I have to rollback both savepoints i.e. savepoint 1 & 2. So My question is how to find out that,which transaction resulted to the exception as well as can I get status of savepoints?

Comment: In general: you can't. You need to track this yourself.

Comment: Ok ...anyway I have gor the rid of it....